# trouble removing element using remove()

Tags: jquery

Im having some trouble removing part of a cloned element:

```
console.log($(this).closest('tr').clone().find('td:last')); //this is the td that i want to remove
            $(this).closest('tr').clone().remove('td:last').append('<td><input type="button" value="Del" class="removesystem"/></td>').appendTo('.targetbox table'); //doesnt get removed here. i tried with .end() after remove() as well, without any success.
```

Have i missed something? Thanks

Comment: Share some markup or a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove only works on selected elements see the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Select the correct element and remove it:

```
$(this).closest('tr').clone().find('td:last').remove().end().append( yadda yadda yadda )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `.remove(/*filters*/)` accespts only filters, of the selected elements,

so you should do this.

```
$(this).closest('tr').clone().find('td:last');

$(this).closest('tr').clone().find('td').remove(':last').append('<td><input type="button" value="Del" class="removesystem"/></td>').appendTo('.targetbox table');
```

also remove `console.log();` as it may not work, if console is not open

Comment: Remove returns the removed element

Comment: I didn't say anything about the return, I said it accepts as an attr the selectors filtered to be removed. `$('td').remove(':last');` it will remove the `last` `td` as oppose to every `td`

Answer (score 0):

Delete a clone? Append to a deleted object?

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').remove();
```